# Google Oauth with Micronaut

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, micronaut

I currently have an app that has a mobile app frontend (Kotlin) with micronaut as the backend. I want to implement Google OAuth on the backend. Would I send the authorization code that the mobile app receives to the backend, which would then send that code to the token endpoint to get the token? How would the authorization flow work?